# why is a object member variable not being updated in the file?

Tags: c++, class, oop, object

So i'm writing down these objects in file, reading them, and later updating stock count. I have written two objects in file and they're being read perfectly but not updating the stock after the decrement function is called. I don't want to change the data type of ID from string to character array as that won't be feasible for my project. Can it work with string?

Please help.Where's my code going wrong

```
  #include<fstream>
  #include <string> 
  #include <iostream> 
  #include<cstring>
  using namespace std; 
  class Item
  {
string ID; 
char  name[10]; 
int stock; 
public: 
Item()
{

}
Item(string id, char n[10], int s)
{
    ID=id; 
    strcpy(name,n); 
    stock=s; 
}
void writeuser(){
      fstream fp;
      fp.open("harmain.dat",ios::out|ios::app);
      fp.write((char*)this,sizeof(Item));
      fp.close();
}
void readuser(string id){
     fstream fp;
      fp.open("harmain.dat",ios::in|ios::out);
      fp.read((char*)this,sizeof(Item));
      while(1){
          if(this->ID!=id){
              cout<<"name:"<<name;
              cout<<"stock"<<stock;
              break;
          }
         fp.read((char*)this,sizeof(Item));
      }
      fp.close();
}
void decrement(string id){
        fstream fp;
        Item test;
      fp.open("harmain.dat",ios::in|ios::out);
      fstream fp2;
      fp2.open("temp.dat",ios::out|ios::in);
      while( fp.read((char*)&test,sizeof(Item))){
          if(test.ID==id){
             test.stock=test.stock-1;
             fp2.write((char*)&test,sizeof(Item));
          }else{
             fp2.write((char*)&test,sizeof(Item));
          }
      }
      remove("harmain.dat");
      rename("temp.dat","harmain.dat");
      fp.close();
      fp2.close();
     }
    };

  int main 
  {    Item i1;
 i1.readuser("APP01");
   cout<<endl;
i1.decrement("APP01");
i1.readuser("APP01");
  //  Item i1("APP01", "Apple",100);
   // i1.writeuser();
 //  i1.readuser("APP01");
 //   Item i2("BAN01","Bananas",200);
//    i2.writeuser();
   }
```

Comment: No, it won't work with strings. You have to serialize your class.

Comment: You should fix your indentation :)